# using else if in a bash alias(homework)

Tags: linux, bash, alias

For my homework I need to write an alias that checks if a given file is regular and readable. The problem i am getting is that if i include else if or elif i get this error...

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

here is my code...

```
alias getname='read filename'

alias vfile='getname; if [ ! -f $filename ]; then echo "Irregular file"; (exit 1); elif [ ! -r $filename]; then echo "Not readable"; (exit 2); fi;'
```

I need to use an else if so that if there is an error only one statement will be printed.

I am aware that a shell function or script would be more practical but for the assignment I have to use an alias. I am still very new to UNIX so any help will be very much appreciated.

edit:
I do have to use an alias, it is a file name that you give (a static file) and even when I change out`else if` for `elif` I still receive the syntax error I described in the question.

EDIT2: 
I found the problem, I removed the `fi;` before the elif statement but now i receive a `missing ']'`error.

Comment: What does your code look like when you include the `else`?

Comment: You are using `else if`, but the correct syntax is `elif`.

Comment: even when i use elif i still get the syntax error

Comment: Do you strictly have to use alias? Which version of Bash are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to be able to accomplish your task.  Do you need to check if a static file is regular and readable or if a given file is?  Because I don't think alias's support positional parameters.

Comment: You were getting the missing `']'` error because you had your bracket butted up to the `$filename` variable in your `elif` statement.  So it didn't know where that variable ended.

Answer (score 1):

So this worked for me:

```
alias vfile='read -p "Enter the filename: " MY_FILE; if [ ! -f $MY_FILE ]; then echo "Irregular file"; (exit 1); elif [ ! -r $MY_FILE ]; then echo "Not readable"; (exit 2); fi'
```

**EDIT**
I see what you did there =)

Just for readability here is the command broken out:

```
alias vfile='read -p "Enter the filename: " MY_FILE; \
if [ ! -f $MY_FILE ]; then \
echo "Irregular file"; \
(exit 1); \
elif [ ! -r $MY_FILE ]; then \
echo "Not readable"; \
(exit 2); \
fi'
```